# Reportlab utf encoding Latvian

Tags: python, reportlab

Was trying to print out some text in Latvian.
Symbols are displayed incorrectly.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics


def add_image(image_path):
    my_canvas = canvas.Canvas("canvas_image.pdf", pagesize=A4)
    my_canvas.drawImage(image_path, 30, 750, width=50, height=50)
    my_canvas.setFont("Times-Roman", 11)
    my_canvas.drawString(30, 715, u"MĀKSLĪGA INTELEKTA ĢENERĒTS IZRAKSTS".encode("utf-8"))
    my_canvas.save()
```

I tried to add utf encoding.
[image]

Comment: Does the font you're using support those codepoints?

Comment: It is times new roman, it should support

Comment: Could you try Segoe UI instead and does this font type work?

Comment: Not sure how to import this font

Comment: Are you sure your source code is saved using UTF-8 encoding, too?

Comment: does `my_canvas.drawString` expect a `bytes` object? Do you have a link to the documentation anywhere?

Comment: @rodrigo yes, the file is utf-8